# Не устанавливается библиотека boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, boost

Уже второй день пытаюсь установить библиотеку boost, никак не получается.

Скачал версию 1.67.0. Запустил bootstrap.bat, она создала мне b2.exe и bjam.exe. Запускаю b2.exe, она часа 2 что-то ставит и в конечном счёте просто закрывается. Папка stage не создаётся. bjam.exe быстро пробегает и так же закрывается.

Т.к. папки stage нету, то и мой проект в visual studio 2017 не видит `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-sgd-x32-1_67.lib`, мне некуда указать путь у проекта.

Скачал версию 1.68.0 beta, запускаю bootstrap.bat, появляется ошибка `failed to build boost.build build engine`. В файле bootstrap.log не пойму куда смотреть, в нём идёт путь, затем куча .c файлов и так несколько раз.

Пробовал опять запустить 1.67.0, теперь и на неё ошибка как и с 1.68.0 версией.

---

Что нужно из библиотеки:

```
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
```

Указав в свойствах проекта пути к этим файлам, компилятор ругается на единственную ошибку. `LNK1104 не удается открыть файл "libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-sgd-x32-1_67.lib"`

Comment: Из буста редко бывает нужно ВСЁ. Примерно половина нужного вообще в заголовках, достаточно путь к каталогу `boost` добавить в проекте студии, и использовать, например `#include <boost/assign.hpp>`.  Если же что-то нужно из компилируемых библиотек, их можно собирать отдельно, только то, что нужно.  P.S. в первой строке поста опечатка в имени библиотеки.

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, какие именно инструменты из библиотеки вам необходимы, чтобы вам дали правильную подсказку. Часть библиотеки - это шаблоны, т.е. нет готовых *.obj-файлов, все необходимое хранится в заголовочных файлах и компилируется по мере необходимости. Если вам нужны какие-нибудь платформозависимые инструменты, вроде boost::filesystem, вам нужно будет включить необходимый заголовочный файл и добавить дополнительные библиотеки(*.lib[windows] *.a[unix]) в список дополнительных зависимостей (или вручную ввести имена/пути библиотек если проект собирается в командной строке)

Comment: @AlexTitov, в посте написал что мне нужно и какая ошибка осталась. Как можно скомпилировать только нужный мне файл?

Comment: @acade, написал какие инструменты мне необходимы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как теперь получить нужный мне файл?

Comment: @Николай, вы в операционной системе добавили переменную среды BOOST_ROOT?

Comment: @acade, нет. Сейчас добавлю.

Comment: @Николай, правой кнопкой мыши по компьютеру -> Свойства -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> Переменные среды -> Системные переменные -> Создать: Имя=BOOST_ROOT, Значение=путь к папке где лежит библиотека. После этого запустить b2.exe

Comment: @acade, b2.exe вывело: failed to write output file 'libs\config\checks\architecture\bin\msvc-14.1\debug\threading-multi\32.obj.rsp'!

Comment: @Николай, запустите командную строку от имени администратора

Comment: @acade, она и была от администратора запущена. Может надо консоль другую запускать, я про те что с visual studio идут? Хотя я уже на всех на них пробовал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80264/discussion-between-acade-and-).

Comment: Если вопрос еще стоИт, то у меня за минуту собирается командой `b2.exe debug release filesystem` В каталоге `bin.v2` появляются библиотеки `filesystem` и нужная для его работы `system`.

Comment: @AlexTitov, я не знаю с чем это связанно, но b2 мне в конце прям пишет, что папка stage\lib создана, а по факту её нет. Я уже вышел из ситуации, на другом компьютере с собрал boost, там он без проблем собрался и себе файлы забрал.